# Video Lectures on Regression Modeling and Analysis

Tags: references, teaching

I am hoping to build a collection of free video lectures that teach how to:

- **Model** regression problems.
- **Interpret** regression coefficients and the overall fit.

Happy to make this CW if helpful. Please provide links and a short description of the content if possible.

Comment: Have you gone through Prof. Andrew Ng's videos on regression in his ML course (on Coursera)?

Answer (score 2):

[Statistical learning](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/HumanitiesSciences/StatLearning/Winter2016/about) online course by Hastie and Tibshirani has 1) very detail explanations about regression and other modeling techniques in the videos, 2) provides examples with R and 3) comes with free pdf of the books. It requires registration, but it is very good.

Comment: Thanks, but looking at the list of lectures, it looks like only a small part is about regression modeling and interpretation: Week 1: Introduction and Overview of Statistical Learning.
Week 2: Linear Regression.
Week 3: Classification.
Week 4: Resampling Methods.
Week 5: Linear Model Selection and Regularization.
Week 6: Moving Beyond Linearity.
Week 7: Tree-based Methods.
Week 8: Support Vector Machines.
Week 9: Unsupervised Learning.

Comment: Yes, it is statistics course, not on regression alone. In spite of the fact that the lectures on regression are a small percentage of the course, regression itself comes back later in the course as well and different methods are compared to regression. Moreover the help in the interpretation of the (the various) fit(s) is outstanding. Therefore my suggestion.